# How to dynamically load html templates by getting path from a external json file angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, json

> I'm facing problem to load the dynamic html templates that contains some descriptions . the basic requirement i have is when when i click on particular button it should load the corresponding html file . by fetching the path from json file.
>   i'm sharing my code and i'm able to read and display the url from json but i cannot show the contents of that html page

#index.html

```
 <div>
{{descriptionUrl}}

<div ng-include="'./api-data/{{descriptionUrl}}'"></div>

</div>
```

## action.json

```
{
  "Product": [{

      "descriptionUrl":"view.html"
    },
    {
      "descriptionUrl":"add.html"

    }

  ]

}

 #view.html
<h1>view</h1>

 #add.html
<h1>add</h1>
```

Comment: What is the error that you are facing ?

Comment: @Paras : error i'm facing is "<div ng-include="'{{descriptionUrl}}'"></div>" is this correct way to use this?? mu descriptionUrl contains all the html path i have when i click the buttons i wanted to show the contents of particular page(.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, ng-include evaluates your expression against the current scope. So, if you are going to use fixed path, you need to use quotes to make it a String literal. First valid path is

`ng-include="'fixed_path'"`

If you want a path to be dynamically loaded, you can either create path like this

```
ng-include="'partial_path_1' + any_value_in_scope + 'again_fixed_path.html'"
```

Or, if you want to make you code more manageable, you can simply put

```
ng-include="returnPathFromScope()"
```

To answer your question,

```
ng-include="'/api-data/' + descriptionUrl"
```

Comment: I am glad it helped.

Comment: @ Paras : is there any way to do with by writing a function like this and calling it in html  $scope.display = function(){
 var template = $templateCache.get("./api-data/"+$scope.descriptionUrl);   }    <div ng-include src = "display()"></div>

Comment: There is. But it might mess up your scope bindings. You could use ng-bind-html="getTemplate()".
Don't forget to $sce.trustAsHtml( htmlContent ) though.

Comment: :- not working . it is not even calling . some mistake IS THERE https://jsfiddle.net/1sd5kykz/1/ plese help me out

Answer (score 0):

For your dynamic behavior, use ng-include with src as per below.

```
 <ng-include src="{{your url}}"></ng-include>
```

Reference: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude

Comment: but {{url}} this is in string format know the system won't accept it

Comment: you can use string format as well as variable inside {{}}, for string you have to define in " ".